# Pause and resume a ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice

I'm writing a tetris-clone. I want to make the pieces fall a tad faster after every 60 seconds, and for this I'm using a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html):

```
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        levelUp();
    }
}, 60, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Now, I can pause the game, and while paused the game obviously stops doing anything until I resume it. As it is now, pausing the game is well and all for everything but this executor taking care of "leveling up". For example, if I played for 50 seconds, paused the game for a minute, resumed and played another 10 seconds, I would be at level 2, while I'm supposed to be at level 1 (we start at level 0). Is there a way of *pausing* and *resuming* the executor?

Note that simply not leveling up while paused is not enough: if I play for 50 seconds, then pause for 20 seconds and then resume, I would have to play another 50 seconds before I level up, instead of the supposed 10 seconds.

So, is there a way to pause and resume a `ScheduledExecutorService`?

Answer (score 2):

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545204/pause-scheduledexecutorservice) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347155/how-to-pause-resume-or-change-the-period-time-of-timertask) questions. By default there is no support to pause and resume a `ScheduledExecutorService`, it just can be stopped. You have to play with the scheduling of the tasks.

Comment: Neither of those answers my question, but if it can't be done, I guess I'll have to play with the scheduling.

Comment: `ScheduledExecutorService` isn't too flexible this way, so I'd do the scheduling myself in a different way but still use the `ScheduledExecutorService` to run one-time scheduled tasks. Always hold a reference to the next task to be executed and when a pause situation comes I'd cancel the run of the next `levelUp` task and save the remaining time until it's execution. On unpause just schedule a new `levelUp` task with the remaining time.