# Pause/Resume scenario for TimerTask not working

Tags: android, timer, timertask

Okay, so, I want a task to run and keep running after an interval of time(Like JS' `setInterval()` function, and `TimerTask` has a method called `scheduleAtFixedRate`, which basically does the same thing. However, there is no explicit mechanism to `pause` or `resume` a `TimerTask.`

I read on SO, that once a `Timer` is cancelled, it goes to hell.

I also read that a workaround can be achieved.

Here's my code:

```
Timer t = new Timer();
        t1 = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

               //Do Something like,
a++;

            }
        };
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(t1, 0L, 300L); /*Pretty basic till this line. Just a TimerTask ddeclaration and execution via a Timer `t`.*/

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (flag == 1) {

t.scheduleAtFixedRate(t1,0,300);//This call says "TimerTask already scheduled," even though purge removed it.
                } else {
                    t1.cancel(); //cancelling the task so that purge does something.
                    int a = t.purge();//a is 1. Purge worked. TimerTask was removed from the queue.
                    Log.d("The number of tasks",a+"");//1
                    flag = 1;
                }
            }
        });
```

How do I make this work?

If, however, ScheduleExecutorService could be used, will anyone be able to implement what's mentioned in this comment? [Pause/Resume ScheduleExecutorService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750459/pause-and-resume-a-scheduledexecutorservice#comment43912543_27750554)

Comment: Does your task only need to execute between `onResume()` and `onPause()` while your app is visible and in use? Is there a reason it needs to run on a background thread? Asking because you might want to consider using a `Handler` instead as the use of `Timer` is usually discouraged.

Comment: Suppose the task is running. Then, if onPause is called, the task should pause. And Hold its position while the rest of the app remains useable. And when onResume is called, it should continue whatever it is that it was doing. How can I use a Handler for this?

Comment: It MUST run on a background thread.

Comment: What is the task doing? Not even the timer will allow you to "pause" a task in the middle of its execution and resume it later. Neither will a `ScheduleExecutorService` for that matter without you handling it yourself.

Comment: The task is counting up to a certain point. Do you think handler.postDelayed might work, withme handling the onResume time myself?

Comment: Yes that is what I was originally suggesting. If you are only "counting up" without knowing the other details of the use case I don't see a reason to need another thread. A `Handler` that runs its callbacks on the UI thread looks like it would work fine.

Comment: I just did that, with a 300ms delay, but it hanged the entire app. It crashed, with a black screen of death.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach than using a `Timer` with a `TimerTask` in this example would be to use a `Handler` on the UI thread and `Handler.postDelayed(...)` to schedule the callback.

You are not doing any heavy processing or anything else that would require the callback to be executed on a separate thread and are updating a `UI` element which needs to be done on the UI thread anyways.